# Find all $f\in \mathbb Z[x]$ for which $\exists N\in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $p\mid 2(f(p)!)+1, \forall p>N$ where $f(p)$ is positive

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find all monic polynomial $f\in \mathbb Z[x]$ for which $\exists N\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $p\mid 2(f(p)!)+1, \forall p>N$ where $f(p)$ is positive. $p$ prime
(A monic polynomial is a polynomial but with $1$ as the leading coefficient for $x^n$)

First set $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k=x^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k$$

Note that if $\deg f=0$ then $f(p)=c$, so $$p\mid 2c!+1 \quad \forall p>N$$

but since we have arbitrarily large prime numbers, we know $\exists p>2c!+1$ which means $$p\not\mid 2c!+1$$

I don't know what to do in the other cases

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: From Modern olympiad number theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ divides $2m!+1$ for any $m$, then $m\leq p$. Therefore, for all large primes $p$, $f(p)\leq p$, which means that either $f$ is constant (you've dealt with this case) or $f(x)=x-c$ for some constant $c$.

Now, note that for primes $p>c$,
$$(-1)^{c-1}\equiv \binom{p-1}{c-1}=\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-c)!(c-1)!}\equiv -(p-c)!^{-1}(c-1)!^{-1}\pmod p,$$
so if $p$ divides $2(p-c)!+1$ then
$$p\mid 2+(-1)^c(c-1)!.$$
So, $(-1)^c(c-1)!+2=0$. This implies $c=3$, which works. So $f(x)=x-3$ is the only such polynomial.

Comment: why add the condition 'for any $m$'? If $p\mid 2m!+1$ and $m\ge p$ then $p\mid m!$ which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @PNT I used the wording "for any $m$" to emphasize that this was a general property of the condition "$p\mid 2m!+1$," and wasn't specific to the condition at hand where $m$ is the value of a particular polynomial at $p$. The sparser "Whenever $p$ divides $2(f(p))!+1$, $f(p)<p$" would also be just fine.